# SQL CASE rolling date difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I pull the annual rolling date difference within a case statement?  Or, if there's a better method that would work.  When the NXT Anniversary Date month is after the current month, then I need the date to roll to the next year.  I need to see the next anniversary dates that would be coming up in 2022.

For example:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Below is the code I was using, which works great for the current year.

```
Declare @prevbiz as Date set @prevbiz = DateAdd(day,Case (Datepart(Weekday,Cast(GetDate() as Date))) 
                                                When 2 then -3
                                                Else -1
                                                End, Cast(GetDate() as Date));  
    
DECLARE @prev12MONTHS AS DATE set @prev12MONTHS  = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, DAY(@enddate)-1)
    
    SELECT
        ANNUALREVIEWDATE
    ,   'NXT Anniversary Date'  =  CASE WHEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, ANNUALREVIEWDATE, @prevbiz), ANNUALREVIEWDATE)  <= @prev12MONTHS 
                                THEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, ANNUALREVIEWDATE, @prevbiz) -1, ANNUALREVIEWDATE)
                                 ELSE DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, ANNUALREVIEWDATE, @prevbiz), ANNUALREVIEWDATE)
                                 END
    
FROM [table]
```

Comment: Because you used an image? And not just for this question - for multiple questions. You have too much rep and experience to not know that images should not be used for posting vital information. And really - how much effort do you have using "yy" rather than "year" in your dateadd functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're just looking to decide whether the anniversary has already passed and should then be advanced to next year.

```
datefromparts(
    year(getdate()) +
        case when datefromparts(2000, month(getdate()), day(getdate()))
               >= datefromparts(2000, month(X), day(X)) 
            then 1 else 0 end,
    month(getdate()),
    day(getdate())
)
```

You could also just compare month and day parts individually. Year 2000 is just an arbitrary year that happens to have a leap day.

Comment: I used your code into additional temp table with a case statement to get the results I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my findings on your question, this maybe could help you.

```
with dates(annualAnniversary) as (

    select DateAdd(month,6,DateAdd(year,-5,cast(GetDate() as date)))
    union 
    select DateAdd(month,3,DateAdd(year,-4,cast(GetDate() as date)))
    union 
        select DateAdd(month,3,DateAdd(year,-1,cast(GetDate() as date))) 
    union 
        select DateAdd(month,5,DateAdd(year,-2,cast(GetDate() as date)))
    union 
        select DateAdd(month,2,DateAdd(year,-1,cast(GetDate() as date)))
    union 
        select DateAdd(month,8,DateAdd(year,-3,cast(GetDate() as date)))
    union 
        select DateAdd(month,0,DateAdd(year,0,cast(GetDate() as date)))
      

)
select annualAnniversary, 
      DateAdd(year,DATEDIFF(year,annualAnniversary, cast(GetDate() as date)),annualAnniversary) as needsToShow  
from dates
```

for excluding rows those not meet their own annual Anniversary, You can add this to the above code:

```
where DATEDIFF(year,annualAnniversary, cast(GetDate() as date))>0
```

Output with raw data:

[image]

Comment: check if the elapse days are less than one year and exclude then use the 2022 year and the prior anniversary month and day for the next anniversary.

Comment: @GoldenLion for excluding rows those not meet their own annual Anniversary, I added that. but for calculation next annual  Anniversary that way you're suggesting isn't the good way cause of calling multiple functions in select and when we had millions of records it'll turn into trouble.

Comment: @GoldenLion, efficiency rules when dealing with large data